# XSLT Filter on property

Tags: xslt, filtering, umbraco

I am needing a little help with filtering my xml based on a property

I have the XML in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root id="-1">
    <LandingPage id="1067" parentID="1050" level="2" 
        writerID="0" creatorID="0" nodeType="1066" template="1073" 
        sortOrder="0" createDate="2013-02-04T14:29:39" 
        updateDate="2013-02-07T11:08:27" nodeName="About" 
        urlName="about" writerName="Pete" creatorName="Pete" 
        path="-1,1050,1067" isDoc="">
      <hideInNavigation>0</hideInNavigation>
    </LandingPage>
</root>
```

What I need to do is filter these elements where hideInNavigation = 0

I have tried the following:

```
[@isDoc and @hideInNavigation ='0']
```

(I need the @isDoc attribute too) but realised this would only work if `hideInNavigation` was an attribute of the `LandingPage` tag so I tried

```
value['hideInNavigation'='0']
```

but this didn't seem to do anything either.  After much searching for the answer, I haven't come up with anything so was wondering if it is possible

Comment: `[@isDoc and hideInNavigation = '0']` - you just need to drop the `@` because `hideInNavigation` is a child element rather than an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the current context was the `<root>` element, you could select the LandingPages with hideInNavigation = 0 with:

```
LandingPage[hideInNavigation = '0']
```

If you would share your XSLT, I van give you more specific guidance on how to amend it for this particular case.

And was the `@isDoc` test in your first example something you wanted? Do you want to filter LandingPages that have an `isDoc` attribute and a `hideInNavigation` value of 0?

Comment: Hi yes I would need the isDoc attribute too so I have tried *[@isDoc and hideInNavigation = '0'] and this doesn't work either

Comment: In that case would you please show us your XSLT? At least the `<xsl:template>` that contains that logic, and perhaps a bit more.

Comment: this is the thing that grabs the pages: `<xsl:variable name="items" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc and @level = 2]"/>` - this works fine but when I try to add anything to do with the hide navigation it doesn't return any results

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:variable name="items" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@isDoc and @level = 2 hideInNavigation = '0']"/>` What is `$currentPage`? Why the use of `ancestor-or-self`?

Comment: I'm guessing at this but I think current page is the id of which page you are currently on (or some sort of variable that umbraco passes into itself) and I need to use ancestor or self because I only need the root node of the current page but only if it isn't hidden.  I tried adding the hideInNavigation to the end like you suggested (with an `and` as I got an invalid reading without the `and) but it doesn't return any results

Comment: Sorry, was being a total idiot.  It seems my hideInNavigation property wasn't inserted for the actual page I needed.  Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: No worries, and yes, there should have been an `and` between the `2` and the `hideInNavigation`. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`'hideInNavigation'='0'` compares the two strings `'hideInNavigation'` and `'0'`, which are guaranteed to be different.

In the context of root, `LandingPage[hideInNavigation=0]` would match the LandingPage element in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath return all LandingPage with isDoc attribute empty and hideInNavigation element content is '0'

```
//LandingPage[@isDoc="" and hideInNavigation='0']
```